# postfix smtp server just send status0

Tags: postfix

I'm making a smtp server using postfix,now I can send mail successfully by sendmail command,

but failed send mail via smtp,my test program always block at the readline(read reply of server via tcp) part.

I tried to use the

```
telnet myhostname 25
```

and the server sent status0,then no any reply.

Comment: Then you do not connect to a Postfix server. It must be something else like a firewall or transparent proxy.

Comment: I fixed this problem by add

    smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
to master.cf,sorry for my careless

Comment: Could be a problem in master.cf (smtp pointing to an invalid command - ry pointing it to smtpd).

Answer (score 1):

When connecting, run a tail -f on your maillog file.  It will show the connection being made and then any errors.  There are many ways email can be blocked or dropped, and the error in the log will indicate exactly why.

You may have failed one of your postfix config requirements, or if postscreen is being used, it may be dropping the connection for acting like a spammer's tool.

Comment: Nothing in the log file when i connecting.when I closing the connection it shown

    Apr  4 10:05:46 (none) postfix/smtp[16756]: warning: unexpected end-of-input from smtp socket while reading input attribute name
    Apr  4 10:05:46 (none) postfix/smtp[16756]: warning: deliver_request_get: error receiving common attributes